# how to search for files in Sharepoint, copy in azure blob storage and send customised email if files not found

Tags: azure-data-factory, power-automate

Morning guys, pleas help I am creating a flow where I want to search for csv files (dynamically) in sharepoint, copy the files to azure blob storage and send cutomized email if those specified files are not found using power automate or azure logic apps or azure data factory pipeline

I tried this method https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7PspNF6ybc on youtube but I can only go as far to search files, but cannot get a part to send customised email in condition step

Comment: What do you mean by customized mail?

Comment: from where you want to send the mail from data factory or power automate?

Comment: @PratikLad so the email will be like, Hi Bruce - Please note this file was not found on the sharepoint

Comment: @PratikLad the email can come from either Power Automate or Azure Data factory, depends on which one we can use to automate this

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to achieve your requirement.

First use the action **Get files** to get the all the list of files and folders.
Filter only files from this list using filter like below.

[image]

Next, initialize two arrays, one to specifying the required files and another one for the sharepoint files. Here, I have given a sample files in the array.

[image]

Next, use ForEach and give the filter output body array. Use condition to check the array `filenames` contains the current sharepoint filename or not.
Use `items('For_each')['{FilenameWithExtension}']` in the expression for filename.

In the True condition, take **Get file content using path**. Give your site address and Full path. give `items('For_each')['{FullPath}']` as expression for the File path.

[image]

After getting file content from sharepoint, create the blob for it in the same True condition.

Give the File name expression and file content from the above output.

[image]

After the condition, in the same loop, use **append** on the `sharepoint_files` variable and store the filename.

The above loop will copy the existing files from the array to Blob storage. For the remaining files, we need to send the mail. For that take another for loop to loop over the `filenames` array. Inside it, take a condition and check whether `sharepoint_files` array contains the current file name or not.

If it does not contain, add the Mail action in the True condition like below.

[image]

**Result**:

[image]

[image]

**Code view:**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Filter_array": {
                "inputs": {
                    "from": "@body('Get_files_(properties_only)')?['value']",
                    "where": "@equals(item()?['{IsFolder}'], bool(false))"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_files_(properties_only)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Query"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_file_name_to_sharepoint_file_names_array": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "sharepoint_files",
                            "value": "@items('For_each')['{FilenameWithExtension}']"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Condition": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    },
                    "Condition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Create_blob_(V2)": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "body": "@body('Get_file_content_using_path')",
                                    "headers": {
                                        "ReadFileMetadataFromServer": true
                                    },
                                    "host": {
                                        "connection": {
                                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "method": "post",
                                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files",
                                    "queries": {
                                        "folderPath": "/data",
                                        "name": "@{items('For_each')['{FilenameWithExtension}']}",
                                        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                                    }
                                },
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "Get_file_content_using_path": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                                    "contentTransfer": {
                                        "transferMode": "Chunked"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "ApiConnection"
                            },
                            "Get_file_content_using_path": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "host": {
                                        "connection": {
                                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sharepointonline']['connectionId']"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "method": "get",
                                    "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('<Sharepoint_URL>'))}/GetFileContentByPath",
                                    "queries": {
                                        "inferContentType": true,
                                        "path": "@{items('For_each')['{FullPath}']}",
                                        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                                    }
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "ApiConnection"
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": {
                            "and": [
                                {
                                    "contains": [
                                        "@variables('filenames')",
                                        "@items('For_each')['{FilenameWithExtension}']"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "If"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Filter_array')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Intialize_array_to_get_list_of_sharepoint_file_names": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "For_each_2": {
                "actions": {
                    "Condition_2": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "body": {
                                        "Body": "<p>Hi Rakesh,<br>\n<br>\n Please note this file @{items('For_each_2')} was not found on the sharepoint.</p>",
                                        "Importance": "Normal",
                                        "Subject": "Alert - File was missing",
                                        "To": "<Mail_Id>"
                                    },
                                    "host": {
                                        "connection": {
                                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "method": "post",
                                    "path": "/v2/Mail"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "ApiConnection"
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": {
                            "and": [
                                {
                                    "not": {
                                        "contains": [
                                            "@variables('sharepoint_files')",
                                            "@items('For_each_2')"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "If"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@variables('filenames')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Get_files_(properties_only)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sharepointonline']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('<Share point site URL>'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('<Encode URI>'))}/getfileitems",
                    "queries": {
                        "viewScopeOption": "RecursiveAll"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Intialize_array_to_get_list_of_sharepoint_file_names": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "sharepoint_files",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Intialize_required_files_array": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Intialize_required_files_array": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "filenames",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                "one.csv",
                                "mycsv2.csv",
                                "SampleMissing.csv",
                                "dates.csv",
                                "Missing2.csv"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Filter_array": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<Subscription_Id>/resourceGroups/<RG_name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<Subscription_Id>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/azureblob"
                },
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<Subscription_Id>/resourceGroups/<RG_name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<Subscription_Id>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/office365"
                },
                "sharepointonline": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<Subscription_Id>/resourceGroups/<RG_name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sharepointonline",
                    "connectionName": "sharepointonline",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<Subscription_Id>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/sharepointonline"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```